# Better estimate three level panel data with plm() or lmer()?

Tags: statistics, lme4, panel-data, plm

I have a question about an analysis I want to perform with panel data with three levels.

Am i correct if because it's panel data, `plm()` (from package `plm`) would be more appropriate, however it does not fit well three level data. So therefore I have to switch to the lmer-function which can perform better three level models but does not account for the dependency of the error terms due to the same individuals are being interviewed.

My data have following structure: waves clustered into individuals into countries.

Using lmer:

```
model1 <- lmer(formula=y~1 + x +(1|country:ID) + (1|country), data=data_long, REML=TRUE)
```

Using plm:

```
data_long_pm <- pdata.frame(data, index=c("Wave","Individual","country"), drop.index=TRUE)
model <- plm(Y~ x, data= data_long_pm, REML=TRUE, model='within')
```

Comment: Hi Sophie, although you're going to implement it in R, the choice between these alternatives needs statistical rather than programming advice. Please consider migrating your question to the dedicated sister platform *CrossValidated*: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note that there is no argument `REML`  to `plm()`, see the functions help page.